# How would I go about making a caesar cypher decrypter?

Tags: c#, console-application

This is what i have so far

```
namespace CaesarDecrypter
{
class Reader
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Display Welcome Message
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To The Caesar Cypher Decryption Program");
        Console.WriteLine("***********************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Beggining Decryption:");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n Content:\n\n");
        //Loop the program till given a command.
        bool Loop = true;

        while (Loop == true)
        {
            //Read in Text From File
            String text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Grimswolf\Desktop\Text Folder\caesarShiftEncodedText.txt");

            //Display The File Text
            foreach (char c in text)
            {

                //Not Sure What to do here?
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do you with to continue? Enter no to exit application.");
            //Enter "no" to exit the loop
            String Answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Answer == "no") 
            {
                // set loop bool to false so it exits the program.
                Loop = false;
            }

        }






    }
}


}
```

I need it to continuously advance through the alphabet and find a way to shift X places to crack the cypher. for example the output looks like Decryption shift

0 exxego ex srgi

1 dwwdfn dw rqfh

2 cvvcem cv qpeg

3 buubdl bu podf

4 attack at once

etc.

Comment: do you have the decyphered text? how do you know if X is correct? Either a human will need to look at it or you need a word frequency database.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this code:

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherString, int shift)
{
    var alphabet =
        Enumerable
        .Concat(
            Enumerable.Range((int)'a', 26),
            Enumerable.Range((int)'A', 26))
        .Select(i => (char)i)
        .ToArray();

    var map =
        alphabet
            .Zip(
                alphabet.Concat(alphabet).Concat(alphabet).Skip(alphabet.Length + shift),
                (c0, c1) => new { c0, c1 })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.c0, x => x.c1);

    return String.Join("", cipherString.Select(x => map.ContainsKey(x) ? map[x] : x));
}
```

So then you could run this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, Decrypt("exxego ex srgi", -i));
}
```

You get this output:

```
0 exxego ex srgi
1 dwwdfn dw rqfh
2 cvvcem cv qpeg
3 buubdl bu podf
4 attack at once
```

Answer (score 0):

To crack this cypher you need a statistic of how likely each letter is to appear, for example 'a' 18% 'b' 4% etc (you can find such lists online) and a large text. You count the letters, get their perchentage on your text and therefore match them.( for example 'u' 17.3 % is most likely 'a' according to our statistic.

Otherwise bruteforce your way through all possible alphabets,see the outcome and decide yourself(not really what you would call decyphering)
In the event you know at least a couple of words have it return only the alphabets those decyphered words match your guesses